# Running function on data frame elements in R

Tags: r

Working in RStudio, I'm trying to modify elements of a data frame through a function, however I can't seem to get the effects of the function to appear in the data frame. I'm not sure if it's a misunderstanding of the function or of the RStudio environment.

I have the following data frame data:

```
           V1           V2           V3
1              Deformation         Time
2  DP-26193-2       0.0994       0.0000
3  DP-26193-2       0.1858       1.0000
4  DP-26193-2       0.5329       2.0000
5  DP-26193-2       0.5677       3.0000
6  DP-26193-2       0.7262       4.0000
```

I would like to run a function to take the 2nd value of V1 (DP-26193-2) and place it as the name of V2 in place of "Deformation". I'm expecting the following function to do this:

```
clean_table <- function(x) {
  x$V2[1] = x$V1[2]
}
```

However, I'm not able to see any change in the dataframe after this function is run. It still appears as the original dataset. The columns of the data frame are not set as headers.

Comment: Are you sure you want those words in the first row of your data frame? Or do you actually mean to have them become the column names?

Comment: Actually yes I would like to do that. I believe this code should suffice:


`colnames(table1) <- list(table1[[1]][1], "Distortion", "Time")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the data frame in the end of the function. Try this:

```
clean_table <- function(x) {
  x$V2[1] = x$V1[2]
  return(x)
}
```